# loading required package: shiny Listening on http://127.0.0.1

Tags: r, shiny, flexdashboard

I was running my shiny app on my laptop and it was running fine.Today when I press run document in rstudio I get "loading required package: shiny Listening on [http://127.0.0.1:8010"](http://127.0.0.1:8010%22) and i am stuck there

Any thoughts?

Comment: Restart your RStudio.

Comment: Did it many times still the same

Comment: Perhaps you may need to reinstall some of the packages.  Start with ggplot2, plotly, and dplyr.

Comment: Thanks everyone, I reinstalled R and Rstudio and the issue is resolved

Answer (score 0):

I updated all packages and it helped. Here is a list of packages that were updated `"cli", "colorspace", "cpp11", "curl", "dplyr", "ggplot2", "isoband", "mime", "Rcpp", "stringi", "tibble", "utf8"`
You can update some of them specifically and find out which one caused the problem.